# Creating a new object instance in hibernate using a sql query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am attempting to create an object in hibernate using a query, which will then be saved back to the table representing the class.

Excerpt from hbm.xml file:

```
<class name="MyClass" table="MY_TABLE">
<id column="ID" name="ID">
   <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">MY_SEQ</param>
   </generator>
</id>
  <property column="VAL" name="val" type="string"/>
</class>

<sql-query name="myQuery">
  <return class="MyClass"/>
  SELECT MY_SEQ.nextval ID, 'something' VAL from DUAL
</sql-query>
```

Code snippet from test case:

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) session.getNamedQuery("myQuery").list().get(0);
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(myClass);
t.commit();
```

My aim is that there should now be a new record in table MY_TABLE, but the insert does not occur, I assume that this is due the fact that Hibernate does not know that the instance has not been persisted in the db.

I have tried changing the query to read:

```
SELECT NULL ID, 'something' VAL from DUAL
```

But this results in Hibernate not instantiating an object.

So how can i create a new object instance from a query that is not associated with a persisted instance of the class and use this to create a persisted instance?

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** I tested the approach suggested below and I couldn't get it working for this particular scenario, Hibernate expects you to select columns for all attributes while we definitely don't want the id. However, using a `ResultTransformer` did work:

> #### [16.1.5. Returning non-managed entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904)
>
> It is possible to apply a
>   `ResultTransformer` to native SQL
>   queries, allowing it to return
>   non-managed entities.
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
>         .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CatDTO.class))
> ```
>
> This query specified:
>
> - the SQL query string
> - a result transformer
>
> The above query will return a list of
>   CatDTO which has been instantiated and
>   injected the values of NAME and
>   BIRTHNAME into its corresponding
>   properties or fields.

The documentation mentions returning non-managed entities but it also work with an entity (there is no reason it wouldn't work) and I could `persist` the transient entity successfully.

#### See also

- [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://relation.to/2133.lace)

I'm leaving the initial answer for clarity sake.

---

<strike>Maybe the following will help:</strike>

> #### [16.1.2. Entity queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696)
>
> The above queries were all about
>   returning scalar values, basically
>   returning the "raw" values from the
>   resultset. The following shows how to
>   get entity objects from a native sql
>   query via `addEntity()`.
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class);
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class);
> ```
>
> This query specified:
>
> - the SQL query string
> - the entity returned by the query
>
> Assuming that Cat is mapped as a class
>   with the columns ID, NAME and
>   BIRTHDATE the above queries will both
>   return a List where each element is a
>   Cat entity.
>
> If the entity is mapped with a
>   many-to-one to another entity it is
>   required to also return this when
>   performing the native query, otherwise
>   a database specific "column not found"
>   error will occur. The additional
>   columns will automatically be returned
>   when using the * notation, but we
>   prefer to be explicit as in the
>   following example for a many-to-one to
>   a Dog:
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE, DOG_ID FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class);
> ```
>
> This will allow `cat.getDog()` to
>   function properly.

But I don't think you should set the ID if you want to save it and want Hibernate to perform an insert.

Comment: Pascal, the system that i am working on is generating financial transactions based upon services rendered. So what i am doing is scanning the DB for transactions that need to be generated. My plan was that the select would identify and in effect create the required transaction objects, which would then be processed (complex operations) and then stored as appropriate to the DB. In effect I am trying to get hibernate to create the transient objects for me and then later persist them as necessary. A secondary objective is to keep all the SQL statement config in the mapping file.

Comment: @stjohnroe: OK, I see. I did some testing and couldn't get the initial suggestion to work as I wanted. But I've updated my answer with an alternative approach which seems to work.