# Export table from DB to an XML file with Java

Tags: java, mysql, xml, database, extract

I need to read every row of a particular table stored in a mysql DB, then i have to write an xml file extracted from each row.
Which is the best practice for obtaining this target? I should use some java libraries, but i don't know how to choose the exact ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-marshal-example/

From the DB if you use an ORM like hibernate or other you will get your rows as objects and then you can transforme them using JAXB.

Comment: you have many possibilities, either create a JPA entities that describe your DB or use a hibernate ResultTransformer look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266492/creating-a-new-object-instance-in-hibernate-using-a-sql-query

Comment: Thank you jMounir, so now i install hibernate and with ResultTransformer I turn my row in objects, and  then i have to marshall this objects in xml file. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. if you mean by "install hibernate" that you're going to configurate it (add depndency and create persistence.xml file)